# Bootstrap affix and overflow-y conflict

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, scrollbar, overflow, affix

The issue I'm having right now involves twitter bootstraps affix and css overflow-y.

**The Details**

I have a 41 pixel bootstrap navbar fixed to the top and bottom (used for header/footer).

`div.container-fluid` is used as the main content body. I use `position: absolute` to position it between the header and footer and I have `overflow-y: scroll` to make it scroll through overflowed content.

`div.side-bar` is used as the side navigation on the left side of the page and is nested in a `div.span3`. I use jquery to call the affix on the side nav.

**The Problem**

When I add `overflow-y: scroll` to the `div.container-fluid` I get the scrolling in the right spot ... but the affix isn't applied (based on the actions)

But when I remove `overflow-y: scroll` altogether, the scroll bar extends to the whole page (and not just the `div.container-fluid`) but the affix does apply.

Here are two links to one with overflow-y and one without overflow-y

**No Affix effect** http://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/YRxkU/

**Affix effect with bad scrolling** http://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/cKJV2/

I need it so that the scroll bar doesn't extend into the header and footer :(

Thanks for any help!

Vincent Wilkie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `data-spy="affix"` to the #side-bar div. Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/YRxkU/2/

Comment: that link is broken !

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out a solution that worked for me.

I ended up using .affix({ offset: { x: 10, top: 20 } }) to position it properly.

I also remove the overflow.

Thanks!